# R - parse XML getElementById and nodeValue

Tags: xml, r, parsing

Is there a `XML` library for R that would allow me to simply do this :

```
desiredValue <- getElementById("myDesiredId").NodeValue()
```

I'm looking for a library that is short and simple.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean package, not library, and yes there is.  It's called `XML`.

[CRAN link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) and [Windows binary](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/).